# Correct output from multiple parse defs in Scrapy class

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I extract data from one page, then iterate on urls from this page and grab some another info from another pages. But output is not correct - see the screenshot. Items from second 'def' goes down in output and their sorting does not match with items form first 'def'! Check me code structure below. THANKS!

```
***

def parse(self, response):
    rows = ***

    for row in rows:
        item = Items()
        item['number'] = ***
        item['name'] = ***
        ***
        yield item

        urls = ***

        for url in urls.extract():
            yield Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url), callback=self.parse_player)

def parse_player(self, response):
    item = Items()
    item['mainposition'] = ***
    item['altposition'] = ***
    yield item
```

result is on screenshot: https://snag.gy/tCaDm3.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should collect name and etc on first page; then don't yield it, just pass it via `meta` to next page; and only then yield whole item. Like here:

```
def parse(self, response):
    rows = ***
    for row in rows:
        item = Items()
        item['number'] = ***
        item['name'] = ***
        # don't yield item here!

        urls = ***
        for url in urls.extract():
            yield Request(response.urljoin(url), self.parse_player, meta={'item': item})

def parse_player(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['mainposition'] = ***
    item['altposition'] = ***
    yield item
```